# How could return events of specific args?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, nodejs

In my solidity contract, I just have one event which is:

```
transferOwnerShip (uint  id, address indexed newowner);
```

and I want to filter the events log in order to **retrieve only the events that belong to specific **newowner** address**

I used this JavaScript code

```
 var newlog;
         var events = DeviceManagerContractInstance.allEvents(
           {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'} , 
           {newowner:"0xe6b56e8f11f2dd687d63c75cda3f261ae1124054"});

         events.get(function(error, log)  {

          if(!error)

           {           

             console.log(log);

        for( var property in log) {
        newlog += "Event " + property + ': '+'\n' + JSON.stringify(log[property],null,4)+'\r\n';

            document.getElementById("eventID").innerHTML = newlog;

        }

            }

   });
```

where *DeviceManagerContractInstance* is my contract instance

**but I received all the events for all addresses. So, What is the best way to retrieve event based on specific data args?**

**Besides, Is there any way to print specific data from the event instead of the whole object.**

- Truffle v5.0.27 (core: 5.0.27)
- Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
- Node v10.15.3
- Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37
- geth Version: 1.9.6-stable

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but first double check if your contract instance is defined properly:

```
DeviceManagerContractInstance.getPastEvents('transferOwnerShip', {
    filter: {newowner: "0xe6b56e8f11f2dd687d63c75cda3f261ae1124054"},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result, 'result');
    } else {
        console.log(error, 'error')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Miroslav for ur answer, I tried but my Dapp threw this error _(DeviceManagerContractInstance.getPastEvents is not a function)_ , besides, this is how I defined my contract instance 
          **App.contracts.DeviceManager.deployed().then(function(instance) {
          DeviceManagerContractInstance = instance;**

Comment: Ok, this happens, because most likely your web3 provider is overwriting the web3 version of your library and you end up using web3 version 0.2.x. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents Look here the method I suggested is for web3 1.x.x and https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents .allEvents() is part of the web3 0.2.x documentation. What you have to do is this:

Comment: DeviceManagerContractInstance.transferOwnerShip({ newowner: "0xe6b56e8f11f2dd687d63c75cda3f261ae1124054" }, { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }, function(error, result) { if (!error) { console.log(result); } });

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work, and my output showed an empty array object. As well, I noticed that I have to use **allEvents** to have an output, otherwise, it throws an error or an empty array object. **length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []**
 Any new suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this please:
DeviceManagerContractInstance.transferOwnerShip({
        newowner: '0xe6b56e8f11f2dd687d63c75cda3f261ae1124054'
    }, {
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
    }).get(function (error, eventResult) {
        console.log(eventResult, 'eventResult');
    });

Comment: I tried your last solution, but nothing change, it prints all events. To solve my issue, I used If and For loop and it works. I don't know if it's correct to use my solution in this state but I didn't have another way. Thanks a lot